# Change size of text in UITextView based on content of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, textkit

I am trying to load a UITextView with content from instances of a NSManagedObject subclass (verses in a Bible reader app).

My UITextView is loaded by iterating through the verses in a selected chapter and appending each consecutive verse.

```
NSArray *selectedVerses = [[Store sharedStore] versesForBookName:selectedBook
                                                   ChapterNumber:selectedChapterNum];
displayString = @"";
for (Verse *v in selectedVerses) {
    NSMutableString *addedString =
    [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", [v versenum], [v verse]];
    displayString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", addedString, displayString];
}
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", selectedBook, selectedChapter];
[self setTitle:title];
[[self readerTextView] setNeedsDisplay];
[[self readerTextView] setText:displayString];
```

The above code generates the correct view, but only allows for one size of text for the entire UITextView.

I would like to have the verse number that precedes each verse to be a smaller size font than its verse, but have not found a way to make it work. I've been reading through the documentation, and it seems that this should be possible with TextKit and CoreText through the use of attributed strings, but I can't seem to get this to compile.

I do not want to load the view as a UIWebView.

Any suggestions for this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `NSAttributedString` and `NSMutableAttributedString`. You should read [Introduction to Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html). They're generally like normal strings, but additionally contain attributes with ranges to which they apply. One more method that would be helpful to you is:

```
[self readerTextView].attributedText = yourAttributedString;
```

If you have some specific problems with attributed strings, please post your code.